# iOS 11.2 - Local Authentication - Type 'LABiometryType' has no member 'typeFaceID'

Tags: ios, touch-id, face-id, localauthentication, xcode9.2

I've added face-id support/code for integration in my app, which was working fine with Xcode 9.1 & iOS 11.1.

But the same is showing an error with **iOS 11.2** and **Swift 4.0** in **Xcode 9.2 Beta 2**

Code I've in my app:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                if (laContext.biometryType == LABiometryType.typeFaceID) {
                    localizedReason = "Unlock using Face ID"
                    print("FaceId support")
                } else if (laContext.biometryType == LABiometryType.typeTouchID) {
                    localizedReason = "Unlock using Touch ID"
                    print("TouchId support")
                } else {
                    print("No Biometric support")
                }
 } else {
     // Fallback on earlier versions
}
```

> Error messages are:
>
> **Type 'LABiometryType' has no member 'typeFaceID'**
>
> **Type 'LABiometryType' has no member 'typeTouchID'**

[image]

Comment: looks like missing import of LocalAuthentication framework

Comment: @deathhorse It was working fine in iOS 11.1. It should not if framework is/was missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution from Apple document: [LABiometryType](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/labiometrytype)

> LocalAuthentication ► LocalAuthentication Enumerations ► LABiometryType

**LABiometryType**

It is an enum type of constant which support types of biometric authentication.

Apple has changed title/name of constant elements from iOS 11+.

- `typeFaceID ▶ faceID`
- `typeTouchID ▶ touchID`

and one more new enum element is added: `.none` which is a part of beta version at this time.

[image]

Comment: How do we code this so it works with both Xcode 9.1 *and* Xcode 9.2? There is no #if for Xcode version. For now I am creating my own value with `let faceIDRawValue = 2` and using that.